# python json to csv，json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 67 (char 66)，How to skip errors

Tags: python, json, csv

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 67 (char 66)

Python cannot recognize some characters in JSON. I tried a lot of encoding, but it still cannot be displayed correctly. The JSON file is very large, I want to skip unrecognized lines and continue working

Below is my code, help me modify it. Use parameters 'ignore'

```py
# -*-coding:utf-8-*-
import csv
import json
import sys
import codecs


def trans(path):
    jsonData = codecs.open('‪C:/Users/jeri/Desktop/1.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    # csvfile = open(path+'.csv', 'w')
    # csvfile = open(path+'.csv', 'wb')
    csvfile = open('‪C:/Users/jeri/Desktop/1.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8',
                   newline='')
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    flag = True
    for line in jsonData:
        dic = json.loads(line)
        if flag:
            keys = list(dic.keys())
            print(keys)
            writer.writerow(keys)
            flag = False
        writer.writerow(list(dic.values()))
    jsonData.close()
    csvfile.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = str(sys.argv[0])
    print(path)
    trans(path)
```

Comment: The "open" functions you use have a parameter to ignore decoding errors. Read the docs about them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and ask a clear question, making sure to highlight: 1) show an exact example of what your input looks like; 2) show exactly what the output should be and explain what processing you are trying to do; 3) show exactly what happens when you run the code, by copying and pasting [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) error messages, formatted as code.

Comment: There is no reason to use the `codecs` module for ordinary cases in 3.x, and JSON is inherently supposed to be in UTF-8 encoding anyway. It sounds like there is something wrong with your actual file.

Comment: You say you have a large input file, but the portion you quoted of the error message says that there is already a problem on the first line of the file. You  should be able to create a small example file that reproduces the problem. Alternately, if the file is created by other code that's under your control, the problem could be in *that* code.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with the encoding of some JSON text. I have successfully converted some of them, but some of them cannot be converted. Python prompt: "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError". I found the characters that cannot be converted, and found that these characters are not suitable for any encoding. I changed a lot of encodings, but none of them can be displayed correctly, so I hope that python can skip the unrecognized characters and continue to convert other correct texts.

Answer (score -2):

try to create a brand new file and paste your json data there and change extension to .json try to import that file and see if that fix the error

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.